# Android SQLite Database not fully commiting? Changes until Activity ends?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Sorry for the long description, it's hard to describe my problem without giving you some background.

Okay so I have an app that uses one SQLite database and has two tables in it Table 1 and Table 2. I have a main activity with fragment with a button that starts my Log activity with fragment. The Log activity has a tabbed viewpager and in each view of the viewpager is a listview (Tab 1 listview and Tab 2 listview) with data from the corresponding tables (Table 1 and Table 2) in the database.

So when I'm in my Log Activity with Fragment I can click on the Tab 1 and it will populate the Tab 1 listview with the data from the Table 1 in my database. When I click on Tab 2 it'll populate the Tab 2 listview with the data from my Table 2 in my database. Each tab has it's own fragment. Tab 1 fragment and Tab 2 fragment.

So to explain my issue I'll just focus on my Tab 1, because both tabs are doing the same time.

WHAT WORKS:

Let me explain first though that if I add Data X into my Tab 1, Table 1, it will populate Listview 1 with Data X and add the Data X into my Table 1 just fine. I can Log.d my Table 1 and see it got entered just fine. If I press back on the phone to go back to my Main Activity with Fragment and then decide to go back into my Log Activity with Fragment it will populate the Listview 1 just fine with Data X and Data X is still in my Table 1, because again I can Log.d my Table 1 and see the data has been entered just fine. If I delete Data X now after having gone to the Main Activity and back into the Log Activity the Data X will delete from my Table 1 just fine and it will be removed from my Listview 1. I can log.d my Table 1 after deleting and see it has been deleted from my Table 1.

WHAT DOESN'T WORK:

So my actual issue is when I add lets say Data X and Data Y into my Tab 1, Table 1 of my database. The Listview 1 will populate with Data X and Data Y and insert Data X and Data Y into the database just fine because I can Log.d the table and see Data X and Data Y have been entered into my table.... But now lets say I decide to instantly delete the Data Y (While have never left the Log Activity this time) it will not delete from the Table 1 but it will delete Data Y from my Listview 1. So now when I Log.d my Table 1 I see that I still have Data X and Data Y in my Table 1, but my Listview 1 shows only Data X. If I now press the back button and go back to my Main Activity, and then again go back into my Log Activity it will populate my Tab 1 Listview 1 with Data X and Data Y because Data Y was not actually removed from my Table 1.

It seems as if I can't Delete or Edit freshly entered Data into my Tables without first leaving my Log Activity and going back into it to "Commit/Finalize" the data entered into the Table 1. My Insert, Update, and Delete functions work just fine after I have left the Logs Activity after adding fresh data and then going back into my Logs Activity. But My Delete and Update functions do not work properly if I add fresh data and then instantly try to alter that data. My Listview is updating and populating correctly though.

WHAT I'VE RESEARCHED AND TRIED:

I've made sure I have one instance of my SQLiteOpenHelper and my SQLiteDatabase variables. I have also tried to open the database before every insert, edit, or delete and then close it after I inserted, editted, or deleted. It didn't seem to have any effect. Currently i have the datasource get closed onPause() and opens again on onResume(). And finally I have tried setting up a  setTransactionSuccessful() and then endTransaction() after beginTransaction() for each Insert, Update, or Delete.

CURRENT IDEAS:

I'm thinking it might have to do with my id's of my entries in my Tables... I believe it should auto increment the id when a new entry is added to the table. They might not be what I'm expecting them to be when the data is added and then instantly try to alter the data. The id's shouldn't change though when I back out of the Log activity and go back in though so I'm not too sure.

CODE:

Here is code for one of my Tab fragments I stripped out a lot of stuff due to size of the file.

```
public class LogOilTabFragment extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getActivity();

    DataSource.getInstance(mContext).open();

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.oil_list);

    arrayOfLogs = new ArrayList<Log>();

    arrayOfLogs = DataSource.getInstance(mContext).getAllLogs(LogsContract.OilTable.TAG);
    mAdapter = new LogAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfLogs);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    DataSource.getInstance(mContext).open();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    DataSource.getInstance(mContext).close();
    super.onPause();
}



private void addLog() {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.add_edit_log, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setView(view);

    alert.setPositiveButton("ADD LOG", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String date = dateInput.getText().toString();
            String amount = amountInput.getText().toString();
            String miles = milesInput.getText().toString();

            if (error_count == 0) {
                Log log = new Log();
                log.setmDate(date);
                log.setmAmount(amount);
                log.setmMiles(miles);

                DataSource.getInstance(mContext).insert(date, amount, miles, OilTable.TAG);
                mAdapter.add(log);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition);
            }
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });
    alert.show();



}

private void editLog() {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.add_edit_log, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alert.setView(view);

    Log log = null;
    //Pre fill in the edit text views with the data already in the database
    if (mAdapter.getCount() > 0 && mPosition >= 0) {
        log = (Log) mAdapter.getItem(mPosition);
        dateInput.setText(log.getmDate());
        amountInput.setText(log.getmAmount());
        milesInput.setText(log.getmMiles());
    }

    alert.setPositiveButton("EDIT LOG", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String date = dateInput.getText().toString();
            String amount = amountInput.getText().toString();
            String miles = milesInput.getText().toString();

            if (error_count == 0) {

                Log log = (Log) mAdapter.getItem(mPosition);
                                  DataSource.getInstance(mContext).edit(log.getmId(), date, amount, miles, OilTable.TAG);
                mAdapter.clear();
                arrayOfLogs = new ArrayList<Log>();

                arrayOfLogs = DataSource.getInstance(mContext).getAllLogs(OilTable.TAG);
                mAdapter.addAll(arrayOfLogs);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}

private void deleteLog() {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.delete_log, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alert.setView(view);

    alert.setPositiveButton("DELETE LOG", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Log log = null;

            if (mAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
                log = (Log) mAdapter.getItem(mPosition);
                                        DataSource.getInstance(mContext).delete(log, OilTable.TAG);

                mAdapter.remove(log);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    });

    alert.show();

}
```

Here is my class that has my Insert, Update, and Delete code from my DataSource

```
public class DataSource {

public static DataSource dataSource;

private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;
private LogsDBHelper mLogsDBHelper; //LogsDBHelper Extends SQLiteOpenHelper
}

//String of column names for the oil sqlite database.
private String[] mAllOilColumns = {
        OilTable.COLUMN_ID,
        OilTable.COLUMN_DATE,
        OilTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT,
        OilTable.COLUMN_MILES};

//String of column names for the coolant sqlite database.
private String[] mAllCoolantColumns = {
        OilTable.COLUMN_ID,
        OilTable.COLUMN_DATE,
        OilTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT,
        OilTable.COLUMN_MILES};

    public static synchronized DataSource getInstance(Context context) {

    if (dataSource == null) {
        dataSource = new DataSource(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return dataSource;
}

private DataSource(Context context) {
    mLogsDBHelper = new LogsDBHelper(context); //LogsDBHelper Extends SQLiteOpenHelper
}

public void open() throws SQLiteException {
    mSQLiteDatabase = mLogsDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    mLogsDBHelper.close();
   // mSQLiteDatabase.close();
}



//Method takes a string and depending on the string creates a query from the correct
//database table and returns the amount of items in the table
public int getLength(String tag){
    Cursor cursor;

    switch (tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(OilTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    mAllOilColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            return cursor.getCount();
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    mAllCoolantColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            return cursor.getCount();
    }
    return 0;
}

//Inserts a log into the correct sqlite table with the passed values
public void insert(String date, String amount, String miles, String tag) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    switch (tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            values.put(OilTable.COLUMN_DATE, date);
            values.put(OilTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(OilTable.COLUMN_MILES, miles);
            mSQLiteDatabase.insert(OilTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            values.put(CoolantTable.COLUMN_DATE, date);
            values.put(CoolantTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(CoolantTable.COLUMN_MILES, miles);
            mSQLiteDatabase.insert(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            break;

    }
}

//Edits/Updates a log into the correct sqlite table with the passed values
public void edit(Long id, String date, String amount, String miles, String tag){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    switch (tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            values.put(OilTable.COLUMN_DATE, date);
            values.put(OilTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(OilTable.COLUMN_MILES, miles);
            mSQLiteDatabase.update(OilTable.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            values.put(CoolantTable.COLUMN_DATE, date);
            values.put(CoolantTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(CoolantTable.COLUMN_MILES, miles);
            mSQLiteDatabase.update(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
    }
}

//Deletes a log into the correct sqlite table based on the log id.
public void delete(Log log, String tag) {
    long id = log.getmId();

    switch(tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            mSQLiteDatabase.delete(OilTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    OilTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            mSQLiteDatabase.delete(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    CoolantTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
            break;
    }
}

//Returns an Arraylist of all of the logs from the table specified from the passed in value.
public ArrayList getAllLogs(String tag){

    ArrayList logs = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor;
    Log log;

    switch(tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(OilTable.TABLE_NAME,
                mAllOilColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                log = cursorToLog(cursor);
                logs.add(log);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    mAllCoolantColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                log = cursorToLog(cursor);
                logs.add(log);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            break;
    }

    return logs;
}

//Used in local method getAllLogs()
private Log cursorToLog(Cursor cursor) {
    Log log = new Log();
    log.setmId(cursor.getLong(0));
    log.setmDate(cursor.getString(1));
    log.setmAmount(cursor.getString(2));
    log.setmMiles(cursor.getString(3));
    return log;
}


//Used to get all of the dates from the specified database in the call.
public String[] getAllDates(String tag){
    Cursor cursor;
    int index;
    String[] dates = new String[0];
    int i = 0;

    switch(tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(OilTable.TABLE_NAME, mAllOilColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            index = cursor.getColumnIndex(OilTable.COLUMN_DATE);
            dates = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                dates[i] = cursor.getString(index);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME, mAllCoolantColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            index = cursor.getColumnIndex(CoolantTable.COLUMN_DATE);
            dates = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                dates[i] = cursor.getString(index);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;
    }
    return dates;
}

//Used to get all of the amounts from the specified database in the call.
public String[] getAllAmounts(String tag){
    Cursor cursor;
    int index;
    String[] amounts = new String[0];
    int i = 0;

    switch(tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(OilTable.TABLE_NAME, mAllOilColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            index = cursor.getColumnIndex(OilTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT);
            amounts = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                amounts[i] = cursor.getString(index);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME, mAllCoolantColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            index = cursor.getColumnIndex(CoolantTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT);
            amounts = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                amounts[i] = cursor.getString(index);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;
    }

    return amounts;
}

//Used to get all of the miles from the specified database in the call.
public String[] getAllMiles(String tag){
    Cursor cursor;
    int index;
    String[] miles = new String[0];
    int i = 0;

    switch(tag) {
        case OilTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(OilTable.TABLE_NAME, mAllOilColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            index = cursor.getColumnIndex(OilTable.COLUMN_MILES);
            miles = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                miles[i] = cursor.getString(index);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;
        case CoolantTable.TAG:
            cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME, mAllCoolantColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            index = cursor.getColumnIndex(CoolantTable.COLUMN_MILES);
            miles = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                miles[i] = cursor.getString(index);
                i++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.close();
            break;
    }

    return miles;
}


}
```

LogDBHelper Code

```
public class LogsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Application database name and version
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "logs.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public LogsDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // Database creation sql statement for oil table
    final String SQL_CREATE_OIL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + OilTable.TABLE_NAME + "( "
            + OilTable.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + OilTable.COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + OilTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL,"
            + OilTable.COLUMN_MILES + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";

    // Database creation sql statement for coolant table
    final String SQL_CREATE_COOLANT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME + "( "
            + CoolantTable.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + CoolantTable.COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + CoolantTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL,"
            + CoolantTable.COLUMN_MILES + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";

    //Create the tables in the database
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_OIL_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_COOLANT_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ OilTable.TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ CoolantTable.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

}
```

UPDATE #1:

What I've found out after messing around and debugging for a few hours is that when I add a new data item to my table and then try to delete that freshly added item it thinks it's ID is 0... But it should not.

Example:
I have 1 data item in my table. It's data row looks like
ID: 1, Data: "Example Data 1"

Now if I add another data item to that table I'll have,
ID: 1, Data: "Example Data 1"
ID: 2, Data: "Example Data 2"

If I want to delete data item two right now after JUST inserting it. My delete query thinks I'm looking for ID: 0 so it doesn't find it and doesn't delete it. Makes sense.... But if I had my original

ID: 1, Data: "Example Data 1"

And then added a second data item so it now looks like this
ID: 1, Data: "Example Data 1"
ID: 2, Data: "Example Data 2"

And then press the back button to go back to my Main Activity... Then go back into my Log Activity to try and delete data item 2 the delete query will find the ID = 2 and delete the right data item

It's like my ID auto incremented id number isn't being committed unless I back out and go back in and then it finds it.

UPDATE #2:

Solved it,

Problem was in my Add method of my Tab Fragment... I was never updating the Log object with it's new ID after inserting the data into the table...

```
Log log = new Log();
Needed to set ID before adding it to mAdapter
log.setmDate(date);
log.setmAmount(amount);
log.setmMiles(miles);

mDataSource.insert(date, amount, miles, OilTable.TAG);

log.setmId(mDataSource.getLastLogID(OilTable.TAG));

mAdapter.add(log);
```

Comment: please show LogsDBHelper's code

Comment: Added the LogsDBHelper code

Comment: show your adapters code too

Comment: My Log (Listview) adapter, or my Viewpager Adapter? The issue isn't with the Listview adapter or Vewpager adapter not displaying the right information (That all seems to be working just fine). It's that my database isn't allowing me to delete or update freshly added data unless I back out of the logs activity and then go back into it first. Then if I delete or edit the data it will keep the changes.

I wish I had a video I could show. It's hard to explain exactly whats happening and would be easy to show with a video

Comment: Try to explain in another way, because it really hard to take it.

Comment: I know it was really hard to explain and I thank you for trying but I finally figured it out after about 4 hours.... 

I was simply forgetting to update my Log object with it's new table ID before adding it to my ListAdapter... Causing any recently added data to not be accessible by an ID in a query. But would work fine once i went out and loaded back into the Log Activity because my ListAdapter would populate with the full data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it,

Problem was in my Add method of my Tab Fragment... I was never updating the Log object with it's new ID after inserting the data into the table...

```
Log log = new Log();
Needed to set ID before adding it to mAdapter
log.setmDate(date);
log.setmAmount(amount);
log.setmMiles(miles);

mDataSource.insert(date, amount, miles, OilTable.TAG);

log.setmId(mDataSource.getLastLogID(OilTable.TAG));

mAdapter.add(log);
```

Without it any recently added data would not be accessible by an ID in a query because I was referencing my ListView of Logs to get the Log information to edit and delete. It would work fine once i went out and loaded back into the Log Activity because my ListAdapter would populate with the full data including the IDs.